# Span Background

Tags: background, html

I just started at a new job and took over a site from someone who coded a site very strangely. I have figured out most of the issues but have a hiccup that hopefully you guys can help me with.

http://newcombspring.stifel-marcin.com/ is the site. If you go over the Products link you'll see that it drops down and that there is a hover background in place but I can't get a generalized background to show up. I currently have it set to black(#000000) and the only way I've gotten it to work before is by setting both a width and height but as you can see, the different drop downs are different heights so that obviously isn't a solution.

I wanted to see what you guys thought would be the best plan of action on getting this to work correctly.

Comment: The first thing I'd try is removing the <b> tags that surround the span, then changing from <span> to <div>.  You can usually get some mileage out of using more semantic html.  That's probably not all you'll need to change, but it would be worth a try to see if it improves things.

Comment: There are no <b> tags around the spans that i'm talking about.